# HTC One X SMS Font Size Keeps Changing

Tags: htc-one-x, fonts

I use an HTC One X from Rogers (a Canadian telecom operator). I'd like to have my SMS displayed in **small** font, but my phone kept changing the font size back to **medium**, especially after I killed all tasks. How can I set the font size to **small** once and for all?

Android version: 4.1.1

HTC Sense version: 4+

Software number: 3.17.631.2

Comment: The font size of text in SMS app can be decreased and increased by pinch-and-zoom. I hope you are not inadvertently doing that? Also there is no way to block pinch-and-zoom on SMS app.

Comment: @Naveen: I'm aware of the pinch-and-zoom functionality. But I'm pretty sure that the issue I'm facing is not caused by me inadvertently pinching and zooming in the SMS app.